# Table Error while assisng N/A to missing fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a train and test dataset. There are some missing values inside it. I would like to assign NA for missin values. However, I get a error.

Here is my codes :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
import random
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

Train=pd.read_csv('Dataset/train.csv')
Test=pd.read_csv('Dataset/train.csv')
Train['Type']='Train' #Create a flag for Train and Test Data set
Test['Type']='Test'
FullData = pd.concat([Train,Test],axis=0) #Combined both Train and Test Data set

ID_Col = ['USER_ID']  # ID Variables
Target_Col = ["ACTIVITY_DEC_16"]
Cat_Cols = ['ACT_DATE','STATUS', 'TP_CURRENT','TP_CHANGES_NUM','START_PACK','OFFER_GROUP','BIRTHDAY','GENDER','MLLS_STATE',
            'PORTED_IN','PORTED_OUT','OBLIG_NUM','OBLIG_ON_START','ASSET_TYPE_LAST','DEVICE_TYPE_BUS','USAGE_AREA','REFILL_OCT_16','REFILL_NOV_16',
            'OUTGOING_OCT_16','OUTGOING_NOV_16','GPRS_OCT_16','GPRS_NOV_16','REVENUE_OCT_16','REVENUE_NOV_16']  #Categorical Variables

Num_Cols = list(set(list(FullData.columns))-set(Cat_Cols)-set(ID_Col)-set(Target_Col))  #Numerical Variables

Other_Col = ['Type'] #Test and Train Data Set Identifier



Num_Cat_Cols = Num_Cols + Cat_Cols  #Combined numerical and Categorical variables

#Create a new variable for each variable having missing value with VariableName_NA
# and flag missing value with 1 and other with 0

for var in Num_Cat_Cols:
    if FullData[var].isnull().any()==True:
        FullData[var+'_NA']=FullData[var].isnull()*1
```

Here is a sample from my train dataset: (If you want I can upload all :) )

[image]

Here is my lovely error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/isozyesil/PycharmProjects/TaskNo2/TaskNo2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/isozyesil/PycharmProjects/TaskNo2/TaskNo2.py", line 32, in <module>
    if FullData[var].isnull().any()==True:
  File "/Users/isozyesil/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2059, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/Users/isozyesil/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2066, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/Users/isozyesil/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1386, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/Users/isozyesil/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3543, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/Users/isozyesil/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2136, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'ACT_DATE'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does `FullData` _really_ have column `'ACT_DATE'`? (You can check by looking at `FullData.columns`).

Comment: Yes,  It has. I have just ound the problem. I supposed to use delimiter for splitting each column.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :))

Answer (score 0):

Using delimiter solves the problem.

```
Train=pd.read_csv('Dataset/train.csv', delimiter=';')
Test=pd.read_csv('Dataset/train.csv', delimiter=';')
```